# Why this less specification fails to apply the background to the div?

Tags: html, css, less

My goal is to set the background of the div of class `notice-bar` to red when the page is loaded in an iphone or similar mobile device.

This is my `less` file:

```
@mandy: #ff0000;

// extra small
@screen-xs:                  480px;
@screen-xs-min:              @screen-xs;

// Small screen / tablet
// Note: Deprecated @screen-sm and @screen-tablet as of v3.0.1
@screen-sm:                  768px;
@screen-sm-min:              @screen-sm;

// So media queries don't overlap when required, provide a maximum
@screen-xs-max:              (@screen-sm-min - 1);

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

// This does not work too
// .active .content .notice-bar {
//    background: @mandy;
// }

.active .content {
  @media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
    background: @mandy;
    .header {
      display: none;
    }
    .notice-bar {
      display: block;
    }
    .view-switcher a {
      color: white;
    }
  }

}
```

And here is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content active">
        <div class="header notice-bar">
            Expect to be red background
        </div>
         <div class="header header-text">
            Expect to be hidden
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
            Hidden
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would expect the div of class `header notice-bar` to have a red background color when being viewed in an iPhone or other similar smartphones  but it does not. Actually even if I set it explicitly, it does work not either.

```
.active .content .notice-bar {
    background: @mandy;
}
```

What did I miss?

**EDIT**

I followed @Vucko's suggestion and I can see a red background in chrome. However I am still unable to see the same effect in mobile safari. Here is the new `less` code

```
   .active.content {
      @media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
```

Here are the screen shots

[image: Works in chrome]

[image: Does not work in mobile safari]

My primary is to make the `less` code works **with** `media` specification.

Comment: Use like `.active.content .notice-bar{}` because one div has those first two classes.

Comment: What is the CSS outcome of the file? That might be much easier to debug.

Comment: The color will be set on `.active .content` not `.notice-bar`. That code is right!

Comment: @Vucko Thanks for your comment! It works in chrome but somehow it does not work in mobile safari. I have updated my question

Comment: @AnthonyKong your missing the `meta` tag for mobile viewport. Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in your `head`.

Comment: @Vucko Thanks, it fixes the mobile safari issue. Do you want to convert your comment into an answer? So I can upvote/accept given you are the first to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LESS/CSS works, you just have the wrong selector.

```
.active .content .notice-bar{}
```

Means you're targeting the `.content` that's the child of `.active`.

To target `<div class="content active">`, you have to join those two classes, like

```
.active.content{} /* notice there is no space bewteen active and content*/
```

```css
.content .active .notice-bar{
  background: red;
}

.content.active .notice-bar{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="active">
    <div class="notice-bar">
      .active is the child of .content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content active">
  <div class="notice-bar">
      parent has two classes
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Also, to make it work on mobile, then you have to add the `meta` tag for *mobile viewport*.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

More about that in [HTML5 boilerplate documentation](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.3.0/doc/html.md#mobile-viewport).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes more sense now. Where can I find some documentation that explain selectors like "joining class"?

Comment: @AnthonyKong you have a nice article on [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/).

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- Make sure to declare the html5 doctype and enclose your body tags with html tags too
- You need the proper css to call your header and make it red (you improperly defined your compound class):

  .header.notice-bar {background: @mandy;}

Codepen here for you to checkout: http://goo.gl/WlCcUx,

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have fixed up my html file but somehow it still fails in mobile safari. I have added more details to the question and clarify my goal

Comment: Hi Anthony, i just ran the codepen on my iPhone running safari and it works. There's something wrong with your local code still.